# Does youtube player support to show cast button?

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-cast

I'm writing a Android app to play youtube video by using Youtube API, I have a question how to show the "cast " button in Youtube player, if the API is available? if not, how can I cast the youtube video in my Android app to Chromecast or AndroidTV device?

Comment: Thank you all of you, I want to achieve the goal: start playing a youtube video by using youtube API in local app, simultaneously, cast the video to Chromecast or AndroidTV automatically by using cast API(assume just have one cast device), without clicking on cast button. so please help me: (1) I don't want to write cast receiver app; (2) to call cast function automatically without click operation.  Based on these two conditions, what can I do?   thanks for your kindly help!!! Orz.....

Answer (score 2):

YouTube player doesn't have the cast button and you cannot easily cast YouTube content from within your app. Currently, the only solution, is to write a custom receiver and embed  YouTube html player in your receiver and then do some work to get things working to certain extent but it won't be a very good experience; for example, your users cannot skip ads, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, the youtube api does not have the cast button build-in. You can add the cast button to your app (outside the video player) - this guide can help with that: https://developers.google.com/cast/

Comment: For YouTube content, your suggestion is incorrect; one cannot cast YouTube content the way you have described it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Cast Button to Your App but not to the Youtube player.Make Use of this  [CodeLabs tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#0) for casting Other than YT.
Happy Coding..!!

Comment: For YouTube content, your suggestion is incorrect; one cannot cast YouTube content the way you have described it.

Answer (score 0):

Add follow parameter in iframe: `enablecastapi=1`.